# OSX Lion application with iCloud access

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, digital-certificate, icloud-api

I need to build an application for Lion with iCloud functionality.
I know that I have to sign the application in order to use entitlements options to enable iCloud.
I do NOT have to distribute my application on MacStore, just to sell it directly to my clients.
Do I need to subscribe to Mac Developer program in order to get a working certificate? Or I can generate a self-signed one and use it to sign my application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it looks like you have to sign up to the Mac Dev Programme to be able to support iCloud in your apps (you need to edit a setting in the portal to enable iCloud for your bundle ID).

Additionally, it is unclear if non-appstore apps will be able to support iCloud anyway.